# my windows xp sp3 diagnostick:windows could not detect any wired or wireless network cards installed on your machine

Tags: windows-xp, internet-connection, network-adapter, adapter

Problem: cant connect to internet with my new installation of windows xp sp3.

Details:

I have ubuntu in pc that worked with wired internet.

I format all disk and install Windows-XP sp3.

I have auto internet that defined in my router - other computers have internet.

I run diagnoze of IE and get:

```
Windows could not detect any wired  or wireless network cards installed on your machine
```

In Device Manager i have only 1394 Adapter

I dont see any internet adapters.

Edit:

I find with ubuntu livecd that I have hardware: `82566dc gigabit network connection`

Answer (score 1):

I just install the Intel driver for `82566dc gigabit` network connection and it works!

Comment: Remember you have always to install the network card driver for Window-Xp and then it will work also if you have any Wi-Fi device installed on your system then you have to install the driver for that too and it will work like a charm.